# WhatsApp Web Session keeps expiring (iPhone + Chrome on Windows)

Tags: iphone, windows, whatsapp, ios

I use WhatsApp Web on Windows 10 & Google Chrome to connect to an iPhone.

Today, after re-installing Windows, I started to have session issues. On a regular basis (less than 30 minutes or so) I get logged out. Both screenshots are attached. The browser shows a QR code for me to scan and the iPhone still displays the session.

I deleted numerous left-over sessions, otherwise there would be a list on the second screenshots.

This setup worked before Windows re-installation.

**Q:** What could be the cause of expiring / disconnecting sessions?

**[08.08.2017]** Apparently, this is not evident using Firefox. Google Chrome still has session issues.

---

**WhatsApp Web on Google Chrome & Windows 10**, *(QR Code disguised on screenshot)*

[image: 1]

**WhatsApp on iPhone**

[image: 2]